# .NET 4.0 refactoring for yield return

Tags: c#

How can the yield return be refactored in .NET 4.0

```
public static void DoIt()
{
    foreach (int n in Power(2,4))
    {
        Console.Write(n);
    }
}


public static IEnumerable CalcPower(int base, int exponent)
{
    int res = 1;

    for (int c = 1; c <= high; counter++)
    {
        res = res * base;
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? What is the problem with your code? Does it compile? Does it give the correct result? Do you want to remove the `yield return` and replace it with something else?

Comment: I'd change `public static IEnumerable Power` to `public static IEnumerable<int> Power`

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use Tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine. That's probably the way I'd implement it too. One change is that you should use the generic `IEnumerable<int>` instead of `IEnumerable`.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Power(int baseNumber, int highExponent)
```

If you really want to do it another way, you can use LINQ, but in my opinion, it's not as clear as the original code:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Power(int baseNumber, int highExponent)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, highExponent)
        .Select(e => (int)Math.Pow(baseNumber, e));
}
```

The `yield` keyword has not been made obsolete. If the code is clearer with `yield` then use it.